# Unable to get the parameter from URL in angular js and pass it to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a product page where products from database is showing. Code for that product page.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="tab-content vertical col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 left-aligned">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active">
<perfect-scrollbar wheel-propagation="true" suppress-scroll-x="true"  min-scrollbar-length="8" class='ps-scrollbar'>
<div class="ecommerce_product col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="products in data | filter:search | startSearchFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
<div class="thumb">
<img class="img-responsive" ng-src="../upload/{{products.image}}">
<div class="overlay"><a ng-href="#/app/ecommerce/product-edit?id={{products.id}}" data-ng-click="editUser(products)" ><i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i></a></div>
</div>
<div class="product-info">
<h4><a ui-sref="app.mus-song-view"><b>{{ products.pname | limitTo: 8 }}{{products.pname > 8 ? '...' : ''}}</b></a></h4>
<p class="price"> <b>Price:</b> {{products.price}}</p>
<p class="price"><b>Sale Price:</b>{{products.price - products.discount | number:2}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
</div>
</div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Now the problem is i want to edit a particular product in a different page when clicked on the product. I passed the id in the url. But i am not being able to call the url parameter from the controller and at the same time pass the parameter to a php file so that i can call the data from the database.

Is there anyone who can help me from this. Please.

Comment: get url param using $_GET on PHP and use this value in a hidden input field as a value. For that input field define ng-model, the ng-model will give you the value on angular JS. Another way is using angular "Location".

Answer (score 0):

To get a url param you can use: $routeParams

For example you can get the id of a product from that route:

www.yoursite.com/product/id

by doing:

```
var id = $routeParams.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In you HTML/PHP page after you pass param to the URL
Suppose your URL will be `example.com/edit?id=1`
and in the page when you visit above URL.

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<div ng-controller="my_ctrl">
   <input type="hidden" ng-model="myID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
   {{myID}}
</div>
```

Now in your angular controller `my_ctrl` you can access your value (id) by using 
    `myID`
In your controller (my_ctrl):

```
//.............
$scope.myID = ""; //Initial Value
//.............
```

Remember Angular is both way data binding framework, so if you change the value of a model in you HTML will reflect on JS and if you change value in JS will reflect on View.